# Where can I learn about code instrumentation?

Tags: binary-analysis, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis, instrumentation

Currently I am learning about profiling parallel programs. All the profilers heavily use all kinds of instrumentations but this topic is not well explained. Do you know any good sources from which I could learn about instrumentation (static, binary, dynamic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before jumping straight to interesting articles and sources I'll start by defining the key words, just in case.

- **Static analysis :** consists in analyzing the target binary file without executing it. Hence the `static`. Such analysis can be used in order to build a first draft of the application's **Control Flow Graph**, **Call Graph**, ...
  For example, building the **CFG** consists of cutting the code into *basic blocks* and then linking them using the branch targets (if they're not indirect branches).
- **Dynamic analysis :** consists in inserting probes (function calls) around key areas of the binary, running the binary and dumping the probes' results. Such probes can be **rdtsc** instructions on x86, or any other hardware counter.
  For example, dynamic analysis is used by **Gprof** to assess the amount of time spent in each function. Many other profilers such as **VTune**, **MAQAO**, **DynInst**, ... use dynamic analysis to locate hotspots.

Both of these analyses can be applied to a binary file (meaning an executable program), and that's what we call binary analysis.
On the other hand, static analysis can be applied on source code as well as binary. [Lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29), for example, performs static analysis in order to find buggy code constructs.

There aren't many detailed references I can cite, rather a set of scientific publications which span the use and benefits of those techniques, along with some interesting algorithms.

For static analysis I would recommend this collection of articles : [Static Analysis 20th International Symposium, SAS 2013, Seattle, WA, USA, June 20-22, 2012, Proceedings.](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783642388552?cm_mmc=EVENT-_-BookAuthorEmail-_-&wt_mc=event.BookAuthor.Congratulation)

For dynamic analysis I would recommend you going through the publications around of [MAQAO](http://maqao.org/), [DynInst](http://www.dyninst.org/), [ScoreP](https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/scorep-current/html/), and [TAU](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/news.php)